# How do I get my Linksys WUSB300N wireless adapter working?

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, drivers

I have an older Dell Dimension 4550 on which I did a fresh install of 12.04 from 10.04.
My wireless used to work fine with my Linksys WUSB300N, but it doesn't any more.

No Proprietary Drivers were suggested for download by Ubuntu. So I found and downloaded a driver from Linkys' website and extracted it in my Downloads folder: it is a `.exe` executable file.

What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome on AskUbuntu, Jbocean and thank you for your question. Could you please edit your question to add more details? For example, could you give a link to the download you made? What type of file is it (its extension…)?

Comment: Below is what I see in my Downloads folder.  I am not sure if I should double click on any of the .exe icons, or what . . . /home/john/Downloads/WUSB300N_20071204
/home/john/Downloads/WUSB300N_20071204.exe
/home/john/Downloads/setup.exe

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should install Ndisgtk by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ndisgtk). I haven't tested it myself, so I hope it will be clear once you simply launch this app.

Otherwise, I think there is information on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873027) of the Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 12.04 :(